# Как вытащить значение из state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Новичек в React, застопорился на данном моменте.
Нужно при клике на объект, вытащить соответствующие значение из `state`.
На JS реализовывал с помощью дата-атрибут и обращался к массиву классов `"fruits"`.

```
 class Fruit extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            fruits: {Apple: 45, Orange: 40, Apricot: 50},
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="fruitsList">
                <div className='fruits' id='apple'><p>Яблоко 45cal</p></div>
                <div className='fruits' id='orange'><p>Апельсин 40cal</p></div>
                <div className='fruits' id='apricot'><p>Абрикос 50cal</p></div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: fruits у Вас не масив, а объект.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так (добавил обработчик `onClick` на клик по `div` тэгу, а также поменял значение первой буквы у аттрибута `id` на верхний регистр, чтобы было соответствие именам в `state`):

```js
class Fruit extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

      fruits: {
        Apple: 45,
        Orange: 40,
        Apricot: 50
      },
    };
    
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    const { id } = e.currentTarget;
    const value = this.state.fruits[id];
    console.log('Name of fruit:', id);
    console.log('Value from state:', value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div className="fruitsList">
      <div className='fruits' id='Apple' onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <p> Яблоко 45 cal </p>
      </div>
      <div className='fruits' id='Orange' onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <p> Апельсин 40 cal </p>
      </div>
      <div className='fruits' id='Apricot' onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <p> Абрикос 50 cal </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )}
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Fruit />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Первое - у Вас `fruits` - это не массив, а объект.

Второе - нужно учитывать регистр значения, указанного в `id` когда обращаемся к проперти в объекте `fruits`. Для примера `this.state.fruits['Apple']` - сработает, а `this.state.fruits['apple']` - вернет `undefined`.

Третье - функция `handleClick` имеет привязку через `bind` в конструкторе, делается это, чтобы можно было работать со `state`. Эта привязка обязательна для работы `this` в функции (потому что методы класса в JavaScript по умолчанию не привязаны к контексту). Почитать про обработку событий тут: [Обработка событий](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> handleClick(arg){
>   let {fruits} = this.state;
>   for(let key in fruits){
>     If(key == arg){
>      alert(fruits[key]);
>    }
>   }
> }
>
>
> <div onclick=“()=>handleClick(‘Apple’)”></div>
> <div onclick=“()=>handleClick(‘Orange’)”></div>
> <div onclick=“()=>handleClick(‘Apricot’)”></div>
> ```